# React Build runs on local without any issue , and not working on the VPS

Tags: html, reactjs

We have the build folder of the React Project , and no access to the React App itself.
the build is running flawless on the localhost but when we run it on the VPS , the root is not showing and it is not working at all on VPS .

we used apache, Nginx and even serve it statically but none of them was successful

any solution ?

Comment: please provide some code. are you using nginx or apache server? or a custom static serving server? no way someone can help you with this information

Comment: There still isn't enough information here to reproduce or investigate the problem. Please try post a reproduction or at least show the errors.

Comment: "not working at all" doesn't help anyone help you (unless you really do mean that your computer just shuts down or something, which sounds unlikely). What happens that shouldn't? What shouldn't happen that is happening? What did you do to run the app on the VPS?